# What abbreviation should be used to refer to this site?

Tags: discussion

What do you think our site abbreviation should be?

Each SE site is referred to with a shortened abbreviation:

- SF: Server Fault
- SO: Stack Overflow

What shall we use?

Answer (score 5):

I will suggest the simplest of:

GFH

It's easy enough, and means a lot ;-)

Comment: I agree.  G&FH is harder to type and doesn't add anything.

Comment: This is certainly easier to type with the three keys being next to each other, but I think G&FH looks better.

Comment: I think this doesn't look good because it looks like a child passed by and momentarily assisted you in typing.

Comment: Wow. When I first looked at GFH I thought, eugh, no way that looks ugly. But damn it is easy to type. You couldn't have picked better keys to type. I'd +1, but I actually like GSE better as it fits the standard of what we do on other sites.

Answer (score 4):

The two letter abbreviation is not universal with SE, with some single (P.SE = Programmers, W.SE = Webmaster) and others longer (TGO = The Great Outdoors, EL&U/ELU = English Language and Usage) so I'd vote for `G&FH`

Accepting that the length of this may makes using the abbreviation in the icon tricky, this offers scope for imagination for more graphically inclined members.

eg:

- E&LU use a stylised ampersand
- TGO uses a stylised "O"

I'd offer as an idea, a tree or (perhaps more macabre) a gravestone?

Comment: In practice I've found that the use of punctuation in abbreviations can be cumbersome. "G And F H", while technically more accurate, doesn't add any information that "GFH" doesn't already provide. (The ELU site is a case in point.)

Comment: The only problem I have with that is the length. How do we fit that in a sixteen pixel wide favicon?

Comment: @Luke, answer updated with suggestions

Comment: Let's nix the gravestone. Too many negative connotations.

Comment: Agreed, Luke... just making the point it doesn't have to be text

Answer (score 2):

I'd say g.se is a good abbreviation for genealogy.stackexchange.com,
but g.se (also written in uppercase, G.SE) is already being used by gaming.stackexchange.com.

The abbreviation gen.se is not being used, and is not likely to be mistaken for anything else.
It can also be spelled GEN.SE (all-uppercase) or Gen.SE (mixed-case).
However any spelling that includes the full stop, particularly the mixed-cased one, is likely to be shortened further to GSE and GSE is already being used by gaming.stackexchange.com.

GENSE seems a good abbreviation to use;
it is an abbreviation of genealogy.stackexchange, 
it contains letters only, no punctuation marks, in just one case,
it is unique on stackexchange, 
it does not have another meaning within genealogy yet, 
it is pronouncable, and, as a bonus, almost spells GENES.

Comment: +1 Gen SE is the one!  I like it! :)

Answer (score 1):

How about GSE?

Simple, and reflects the SE portion of the site.

Comment: With multiple answers in one post, how will you know what folks are voting for?

Comment: @RobertCartaino - didn't know we were using this as a "poll". Splitting them out is easy enough, though.

Comment: It's not a poll, *per se.* But folks are still trying to establish the best answer by the discussion, vetting, voting, etc.

Comment: @RobertCartaino - fair enough .. they've been split :)

Comment: "G" is ambiguous: "Gardening" already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Has this issue been preempted by the design of the favicon (GH) and the URL (genealogy.stackexchange.com)?

As a "non-professional", I relate more to the Family History element than to Genealogy. Hence my preference would be for FH but practicalities probably require GFH. (But definitely no ampersand!)

Comment: The design of a site is only accomplished after the site is out of beta [FAQ](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/faq#sketchy)

Comment: The StackExchange sites exist and thrive specifically because professionals are drawn to them. Even if genealogy.SE is used by non-professionals (myself among them) I would certainly want to be using a site aimed at experts where I knew I was going to get expert answers to my questions. Along those lines, then, I would encourage this site to be as professionally-geared as possible.

Answer (score 0):

FH: Family History

or

G: Genealogy

or

G&FH: Genealogy and Family History

Not sure what other options there are. I personally like the top option to keep with the 2 letter theme.

Comment: need to split them to single answers: users will vote on the one they like

Comment: One person can't post more than one answer on one question.

Comment: @DmytroZarezenko That is not correct. Users can post multiple answers.

Answer (score 0):

How about **GeFHi** (you could pronounce it "*Jeffy*") for ***Ge*** nealogy & **F** amily **Hi** story

Answer (score -1):

I think better will be GL - GeneoLogy

Comment: we are looking for abbreviations for : 
Genealogy and Family History site